# What is the default optimization level for GWT maven compilations?

Tags: gwt, maven

According to the [Maven GWT Plugin docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#optimizationLevel), the default optimization level is -1. It is not clear to which optimization level this corresponds. So, does -1 mean that the code is optimized at some level between 0 and 9? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342478/what-is-the-default-value-for-the-gwt-compiler-optimize-option/32342540#32342540

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT has 9 different optimization tricks from level 1 to 9 apart from the regular compiler level stuff. However we can opt out of these optimizations by setting it to 0. This is not recommended as commented in the code.

You can probably pick up some more information from GWT source code in ArgHandlerOptimize.java

```
 @Override
  public String getPurpose() {
    return "Sets the optimization level used by the compiler.  0=none 9=maximum.";
  }
```

From comments section of ArgHandlerOptimize.java

```
 * Set the optimization level from the command line.  For now, level 1 is the same
 * as draft compile, and level 9 is the same as the default (maximium optimization).
 * 
 * TODO(zundel): In theory, a level 0 should be possible, where all optimizers 
 * are eliminated for the fastest possible compile.  In practice, code generation 
 * depends on some optimizers being run.
```

Comment: I see that you've used the force/source :)
I've never looked for it, but I assume it must be open source. Where is it hosted?

Comment: Default GWT Optimization is currently 9, see source code of OptionOptimize.java https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/util/arg/OptionOptimize.java

Answer (score 0):

It means it uses the default from the GWT compiler. I believe the default value is 9 then.

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideCompilerOptions and