# What is the default value for the GWT compiler optimize option?

Tags: gwt

GWT has an `optimize` compiler option, referenced in the official docs [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions).  It indicates a range from 0 ("none") to 9 ("maximum").  Unlike many of the other options, no default is indicated.  What is the default value for this option if unspecified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code indicates](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/util/arg/OptionOptimize.java) that the default is 9, but they are thinking about changing it to 8.

```
/**
 * An option that can indicates to restrict optimization in favor of a
 * faster compile time.
 */

public interface OptionOptimize {
  int OPTIMIZE_LEVEL_DRAFT = 0;
  // TODO(stalcup): change the default to 8 to balance time and shrinkage.
  int OPTIMIZE_LEVEL_DEFAULT = 9;
  int OPTIMIZE_LEVEL_MAX = 9;
}
```